# Is there a way to set for protractor a default StartPage?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I need to automate a scenario  which triggers history back actions. So that i can follow that scenario, i need to have as startup page a certain URL.

Where do I have to set the startup page as parameter?

Comment: Please see if [this](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) page helps if not already..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target browser is Chrome, you can use the [`--homepage` argument](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#homepage) (not tested):

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--homepage="https://google.com"'] 
  }   
},
```